# Android NDK: Module depends on undefined modules: log

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I have tried adding APP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS := true to application.mk folder.
Still the error persists.

What can be a fix for this?
My Android.mk folder looks like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libMPMWhiskeyCoveNative
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := SHARED_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := WhiskeyCoveNative.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := liblog 
LOCAL_PROPRIETARY_MODULE := true
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, you have picked up a project that was prepared for an old version of NDK. Please find `log` in your Android.mk script, it should be reffered to as

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
```

The line

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := liblog
```

should be removed, it's a leftover from AOSP build.

Comment: Note that what you will actually have is a `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := log` or `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := log`. This has never had any effect on your build. The warning exists to help you figure out why your build isn't working if ndk-build wasn't able to find a library because you typo'd it or something.

Comment: Now i have added LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog, to my Android.mk file and the error still exists ,

Comment: Your problem was, in the first place, not missing line for `-llog`, but some other line where you have a wrong reference to **log** library.

Comment: Hi Alex, i have included my Android.mk file, can you please help me now with what can be done to fix this error?

Comment: This **Android.mk** belongs to the outdated AOSP build system, not to NDK. NDK does not know how to build STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARY. You will get an error if you try to use this Android.mk file for ndk-build. But maybe somewhere in a jni subdirectory there is the Android,mk file that can almost work with NDK.

Comment: Hi alex, I was able to find an Android.mk file under JNI subdirectory. I made the change, and when i rebuilt the project the same error still persists. I am including the file above.